# Is this canonicalization issue a problem and if so, has anyone solved it? - "Could not canonicalize elem at pos x using key"

Tags: consensus

**We are getting the below canonicalization issue and we are wondering:**

- Is it a problem or is it normal and can be ignored?
- Has anyone found a method to resolve it?

**Here's what we know:**

- It consistently begins at block 2400, and occurs in every block thereafter
- It occurs on --dev, --pruning archive, --unsafe-pruning (for any number) but only on validator nodes (not on sync nodes - that part makes sense)
- It occurs on all node accounts, including Bob and other development node accounts
- Sometimes it is followed by the comment *Offchain: could not prune: no entry in pruning map for block*, but not always.
- It does not seem to affect latency, block production, etc
- We are running the Substrate kitchen sink master 09.26

**Log Sample:**

```
2022-10-03 10:21:57 ✨ Imported #2400 (0xbcf6…a1d1)    
2022-10-03 10:21:57 Could not canonicalize elem at pos 0 using key [12, 109, 109, 114, 179, 231, 150, 242, 116, 82, 112, 40, 61, 105, 19, 211, 47, 138, 252, 83, 183, 123, 184, 153, 192, 116, 137, 163, 141, 85, 35, 94, 41, 140, 112, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
2022-10-03 10:21:57 Offchain: could not prune: no entry in pruning map for block 0    
2022-10-03 10:21:57 ♻️  Reorg on #2400,0xbcf6…a1d1 to #2400,0xf59d…0abd, common ancestor #2399,0xe757…9679    
2022-10-03 10:21:57 ✨ Imported #2400 (0xf59d…0abd)    
2022-10-03 10:21:57 Could not canonicalize elem at pos 0 using key [12, 109, 109, 114, 179, 231, 150, 242, 116, 82, 112, 40, 61, 105, 19, 211, 47, 138, 252, 83, 183, 123, 184, 153, 192, 116, 137, 163, 141, 85, 35, 94, 41, 140, 112, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
2022-10-03 10:21:57 Offchain: could not prune: no entry in pruning map for block 0    
2022-10-03 10:22:00  New epoch 12 launching at block 0x716f…5741 (block slot 554935640 >= start slot 554935640).    
2022-10-03 10:22:00  Next epoch starts at slot 554935840    
2022-10-03 10:22:00 ✨ Imported #2401 (0x716f…5741)    
2022-10-03 10:22:00 Could not canonicalize elem at pos 1 using key [12, 109, 109, 114, 231, 162, 175, 129, 3, 105, 243, 83, 25, 239, 92, 131, 52, 160, 52, 125, 39, 24, 187, 185, 18, 0, 111, 70, 240, 16, 197, 70, 27, 241, 63, 19, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]    
2022-10-03 10:22:00 Could not canonicalize elem at pos 2 using key [12, 109, 109, 114, 231, 162, 175, 129, 3, 105, 243, 83, 25, 239, 92, 131, 52, 160, 52, 125, 39, 24, 187, 185, 18, 0, 111, 70, 240, 16, 197, 70, 27, 241, 63, 19, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: What kind of node are you running? Is this your custom parachain or standalone chain? If so, could you maybe share a link to the code?

Comment: We are running a standalone chain using a pull we did from this repo back in August (should correlate to 9.26): https://github.com/paritytech/substrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is coming from `pallet-mmr`: opened https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12531 to fix it.

---

> Is it a problem or is it normal and can be ignored?

You can definitely ignore those error logs (my guess is you are not actually using `pallet-mmr`).

> Has anyone found a method to resolve it?

Possible workarounds:

- remove `pallet-mmr` from your runtime (if you can, and don't need it),
- run node with extra `--enable-offchain-indexing=true` param,
- filter out logs with `target=runtime::mmr::offchain` ("problem" is still there, but you won't see these logs anymore).

Comment: Adrian! You rock. We are implementing this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Potential answer found in this issue on GitHub... https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12531

Quoting user acatangiu...

> pallet-mmr
>
> uses sp_io::offchain_index API to save full MMR leaves content to
> offchain db, it also defines an offchain_worker() fn that does
> canonicalization of data in offchain db. Issue When
> --enable-offchain-indexing=true is not set, (1) doesn't write anything to offchain db, while (2) keeps on spamming error logs on failures to
> do canonicalization.

So the answer might be simply to use the flag  --enable-offchain-indexing=true when starting up the node.

We will test this today and report back.

Comment: Problem Solved by running node with extra --enable-offchain-indexing=true param